Error usando selenium
estoy haciendo un script con Selenium Webdriver, en mi PC funciona sin problemas pero cuando lo ejecuto en otra computadora hay un elemento al que hay que hacer click y parece que no se puede.
el código es el siguiente:
# Configuro Chrome para que se abra maximizado. Esto es muy importante para que se mantenga la estructura de elementos
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")


    # Inicializo el webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)   


    # Abro el navegador
    driver.get('https://auth.afip.gob.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml')

    # Completo nombre de usuario (cuit)
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='F1:username']"))
        )

        # Lo clickeo para 
        element.click()
        # Borro cualquier cosa que pueda haber escrita
        element.clear()
        # Envío cuit
        element.send_keys(cuit)

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error de ingreso de datos 'Cuit'. Contacte al administrador.")


    # Click en botón "Siguiente"
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='F1:btnSiguiente']"))
        )

        # Lo clickeo para 
        element.click()
        # Borro cualquier cosa que pueda haber escrita
    
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error de clickeo 'Botón siguiente'. Contacte al administrador.")




    # Completo clave fiscal
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='F1:password']"))
        )
        # Lo clickeo 
        element.click()
        # Borro cualquier cosa que pueda haber escrita
        element.clear()
        # Envío clave fiscal
        element.send_keys(clave_fiscal)
    
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error de ingreso 'Clave fiscal'. Contacte al administrador.")




    # Botón "Ingresar"
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='F1:btnIngresar']"))
        )
        # Lo clickeo 
        element.click()
    
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error 'Botón ingresar'. Contacte al administrador.")



    # Pincho "Ver todos"
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='serviciosMasUtilizados']/div/div/div/div[5]/div/a"))
        )
        # Lo clickeo 
        element.click()
    
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error 'Ver todos'. Contacte al administrador.")




    #pincho en CCMA - Cuenta corriente de contribuyentes monotributistas y autonomos
    # A partir de este click el proceso continúa en una nueva pestaña que abre la aplicación de afip
    x = input('Presione una tecla para continuar')

    # Pincho "CCMA - Cuenta corriente de contribuyentes monotributistas y autonomos"
    try:
        # Espero a que el elemento aparezca y sea clickeable
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/section/div/div[3]/div[10]/a/div/div/p"))
        )

        # Lo clickeo 
        element.click()
    
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Error 'CCMA - Cuenta corriente de contribuyentes monotributistas y autonomosMA'. Contacte al administrador.")



El problema se da justo al final del código cuando hay que hacer click en el botón. En mi pc funciona sin problemas pero cuando lo paso a la pc donde va a trabajar el script da error:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (561, 1161)
Entiendo que esto puede ser un problema de resolución o que en la pantalla donde se ejecuta no existe el botón en la posición 561,1161.
la pregunta puntual es como se hace en estos casos? existe alguna alternativa para que un proceso como estos funcione bien en cualquier pc sin importar la resolución o tipo de pantalla que tenga?
Entiendo que usando los XPATH debería estar buscando elementos según la estructura HTML pero tal vez no sea asi y no encuentro la manera de encarar una solución para esto.
Muchas gracias!

¡Hola!
No puedo revisar la página, ya que no me encuentro en Argentina y no dispongo de un "CUIT" para verificarla. Si puedes, comparte el DOM y captura de pantalla para ver qué es lo que pasa.
No obstante, si necesitas desplazarte hacia bajo para seleccionar un elemento, siempre puedes utilizar el siguiente código:
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
ActionChains(driver)\
    .scroll_to_element(iframe)\
    .perform()

Puedes sustituir By.TAG_NAME por By.XPATH en caso de ser necesario.
Documentación
